# Path field gives wrong url

Tags: views, path-aliases

I made change in setting.php for base url

```
$base_url = 'http://www.example.com/drupal
```

Pattern for this content type paths are

```
[node:title]
```

pathauto works ok, in the database path is exactly as pattern.

Problem starts when I want to print Content:path in view I am getting

```
/drupal/[node:title]
```

I have a problem with path field because I want to rewrite result for logo field using

```
<a href="/company/[nid][path]">[field_company_logo]</a>
```

And link is `http://www.example.com/company/[nid]/drupal/[node:title]` instead of `http://www.example.com/drupal/company/[nid]/[node:title]`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `$base_url` variable by no means makes drupal look through every bit of text in the system checking for href's.  So, if you put in

```
 <a href="/company/.....
```

it is going to use it exactly as is because it has no idea to do anything else.  It will, however, be more than glad to put it in front of a path if you use some of its built in functions, for example:

```
 <?php print l('Foo Bar Baz', 'company/foo/bar/baz'); ?>
```

will create a link to `/company/foo/bar/baz` if `$base_url` is not set, or if it is set to `drupal`, to `/drupal/company/foo/bar/baz`.

So, to your problem.  Have you tried Views' `Output as a link` instead of creating the `<a> ... </a>` code yourself in `Rewrite the output of this field`?  That *should* put that `$base_url` in there automagically if in the `Link path:` you enter `company/[nid][path]` (or whatever tokens you need as you use several different ones in your question).

Comment: The things are better when I choose 'Output as a link'. The '$base_url' is now ok, but path has again part of '$base_url' as prefix and looks /drupal/[path]

And the problem still exist, if I enter 'Link path:  company/[nid][path]' now I am getting 
www.example.com/drupal/company/314/drupal/some-title

Comment: I'd then look into your path alias settings to see if you have inadvertently put $base_url in there.

Comment: I take a look at url aliases and as pattern I wrote '[node:title]' nothing more

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this using `Global:php` field and in `output code` I wrote drupal function to find alias

```
<?php echo drupal_lookup_path('alias',"node/".$row->nid); ?>
```

Then as Jimajamma said in views I choose `Output as a link` and in `Link path:` i wrote `company/[nid]/[php]` and everything works.